# The barcode sticker which VFS in India puts on the back of my passport got damaged by water. Will this cause me problems upon re-entering India?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, application-status, vfs-global

I have an Indian passport. I have travelled to UK on a work visa. VFS in India puts a barcode sticker on the back of the passport. Unfortunately, here in the UK, some water applied on the barcode sticker on the back and the barcode is damaged. The rest of the passport is in tact. The first page, the visa page, the last page. Everything is fine.

Is this a serious issue and would I be barred from entering India when I fly back?

Comment: So why are you worried about the VFS sticker ?

Comment: Pretty sure that sticker is just so that VFS could keep track of your passport when they had it.

Answer (score 21):

The VFS affixed a barcode sticker to the back of your passport; this is so that they can track when your passport is sent to the consulate, received at the consulate, returned to the VFS, and returned to the applicant.  Each time the sticker is scanned a computer system is updated with the new status.

The sticker is meaningless to the end-user and it is irrelevant once your passport has been returned to you.

**Is this a serious issue and would I be barred from entering India when I fly back?**

No, the sticker can be removed once you take possession of your passport. It's not a big deal at all.

Comment: +1.. And India or any country generally never barrs their own citizens from entering. Even in a total unrelated case, but also way way more bad than water on sticker, USA still wants Snowden to "come" back..

Comment: @Davinder Well, they might even want some non-US citizens to come and report to authorities ...