# Visa label with alphanumeric number at back of passport, what does it mean?

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens, south-africa

I just got my passport back from visa-processing. It contains a visa-label with a bar-code and alphanumeric code. Does that mean I've a valid visa for South Africa ? If yes, how could I find more information about the visa as in how much validity they gave me and things like that. If it was a denial then surely there would have been something more in the envelope and there isn't. How do I make sense of it and get more information about the visa label.

Update - My bad. The visa was stuck/glued between two pages and was so think so got over-looked :(

Comment: That sounds like the barcode they put on your passport just to keep track of it in their system. If you got a visa, it should be inside your passport on a sticker, and the validity and other information should be printed on it. If you were denied, then there ought to be some kind of letter indicating as such. Can you check all the pages of your passport to see if anything has been placed inside?

Comment: nope, nothing in the passport anywhere :( Done through vfsglobal :(

Comment: Perhaps the denial explanation letter is coming in its own envelope?

Comment: anything's possible but probably will wait for Monday and go to the vfs global, only they will probably be able to help to make sense of this mess, any ideas, tips welcome.

Comment: Is this a passport "pass-back" application? If so, apparently they attach a barcode for this: https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/India/user_pay_services.html

Comment: What does it look like? You can take a picture, black out any personal information, and upload it into your question.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66876/the-barcode-sticker-which-vfs-in-india-puts-on-the-back-of-my-passport-got-damag/66878#66878

Comment: nope, it's not a pass-back application, although hearing about this service for the first time, first-time applicant here.

Comment: Mystery solved then. Congratulations on getting your visa!

Comment: Not quite sure what to do with this question since it's resolved but unanswered. @shirish if you want to answer it yourself that would seem appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my bad. The visa was stuck in-between pages. The label as pointed out by everybody are bar-coded labels to track the passport as it goes through the system (as far as I could guess and the logic of others seems correct.)

Hence answering and closing it, thank you everybody for the efforts.

Comment: You forgot to close it, but congrats on getting the visa! :)

Comment: I think it's closed now, once you select the answer.